# Reshape data using colsplit in R

Tags: r, reshape2

I try to reshape my data using this code but i get NA values.

```
require(reshape2)
dates=data.frame(dates=seq(as.Date("1988-01-01"),as.Date("2011-12-31"),by="day"))
first=dates[,1]
dates1=cbind(dates[,1],colsplit(first,pattern="\\-",names=c("Year","Month","Day")))###split by y/m/day
 head(dates1)
   dates[, 1] Year Month Day
  1 1988-01-01 6574    NA  NA
  2 1988-01-02 6575    NA  NA
  3 1988-01-03 6576    NA  NA
  4 1988-01-04 6577    NA  NA
  5 1988-01-05 6578    NA  NA
  6 1988-01-06 6579    NA  NA
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstacshape` to split the 'dates' column by the delimiter `-`.

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(dates, 'dates', '-', drop=FALSE)
```

Or `extract` to create additional columns

```
library(tidyr)
extract(dates, dates, into=c('Year', 'Month', 'Day'),
                     '([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)', remove=FALSE)
```

Or another option from `tidyr` (suggested by @Ananda Mahto)

```
separate(dates, dates, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), remove=FALSE)
```

Or using `read.table` from `base R`.  We specify the `sep` and the colum names, and `cbind` with the original column.

```
cbind(dates[1],read.table(text=as.character(dates$dates),
                  sep='-', col.names=c('Year', 'Month', 'Day')))
```

---

By using `reshape2_1.4.1`, I could reproduce the error

```
  head(cbind(dates[,1],colsplit(first,pattern="-",
                   names=c("Year","Month","Day"))),2)
  #  dates[, 1] Year Month Day
  #1 1988-01-01 6574    NA  NA
  #2 1988-01-02 6575    NA  NA
```

Comment: Here's an obligatory +1, but can you reproduce their problem?

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Yes, I am getting the `NA` with `reshape2_1.4.1`

Comment: Strange. I'm not. And for "tidyr", shouldn't you be able to just do: `separate(dates, dates, into = c("Y", "M", "D"))`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto You are right, with `remove=FALSE`, it works great

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Are you using the same reshape2 version?